# Basic (and dumb) question - how do I determine if my Armory wallet has any bitcoins in it on a Mac (with an older OS)?

Tags: mac, armory

I am using High Sierra on my ancient iMac and having difficulting loading Armory. I loaded a version that works on occasion - that is offline -- and not showing anything on the balance except (...).  Does this mean it's empty or by having it offline am I missing the access required.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Armory's [FAQ says](https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/faq/#what-is-cold-storage-and-offline-wallets)

> Armory offline wallets require no synchronization except for the initial transfer of a “watching-only wallet” to your online computer. This watching-only wallet functions exactly like a regular wallet, but it does not contain any private data, and thus cannot spend your Bitcoins (making it useless for an attacker). However, it does let you generate new addresses, and verify incoming payments the same way a regular wallet does.

So I would check my balance using the online watching-only wallet I had created when I first set up Armory.

They have a [tutorial on watching-only wallets](https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/tutorials/armory-advanced-features/offline-wallets/watching-wallet/)